# Statistical tests for time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, t-test

I want to use a statistical test to analyze industrial time series data. My question is basically how can I find out which variables are significantly different during normal operation time range and failure time range. Or: There is some maintenance at a device, did some value change significantly after the maintenance work?

I can't use a t-test to compare if the mean values of the two time ranges are different, because my observations within one time range are not independent. I could increase the sampling rate to a very high value and would get always a significant result.

So what is the best way to test if two time series ranges are significantly different (higher, lower, etc.) ?

Thanks!